# How to get rid of Ubuntu's "no init found" error message using Windows?

Tags: boot, windows-xp

I been using Ubuntu for a while and there are no problems but suddenly when I started (technically booted) my Ubuntu I get a error message like this :

> no init found Try passing init = bootarg 
>    //and some error messages follows it

I'm very new to Ubuntu I don't know how to get rid of this. I searched out this problem in Google and I found that we can do solve it by using live cd and couple of steps in Disk utility.

The same Disk check can be done in Windows xp? Is it possible to do so?  Since I have dual boot, I think it will be good to solve the problem in Windows, rather than using live cd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Windows (of any version) don't have read or write support for the filesystem that Ubuntu uses (most likely `ext4`, possibly `ext3`); you need to use a live cd/live usb.

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu, I need to know that normal ubuntu installation cd can be used as live cd?

Comment: @Ant's: Yes. IIRC when you boot it, it asks you whether you want to "try it out" or "install", at one point. "try it out" gets you the live-cd mode.

Comment: I tried using `sudo fsck -y /dev/sda6` to clean my defected parts, but its throwing an error saying that `File is mounted or already been used by another program?`. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Just a note, there is an ext2 driver that allows read-write support for ext3 and ext4 volumes: http://www.fs-driver.org/

Comment: @aking1012: Uh, no. You can't mount a typical **ext4** volume using an ext2 driver, it's not fully forward compatible (It is fully backward compatible though - you could mount an ext2 volume using an ext4 driver, but no such thing exists for Windows AFAIK). You could, under usual circumstances (no data in journal), mount an ext3 volume using an ext2 driver; alas, Ubuntu uses ext4 by default since 10.04. (BTW, if the driver is actually capable of mounting an ext4, the website doesn't mention it at all; as that would be a killer feature if it existed, I find that extremely unlikely.)

Comment: @Ant's: You probably want to post this as a new question, as it's only tangentially related to the original one.